# Dynamically change text of a button in a AlertDialog

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, settext

Edit: The code below works! The error was somewhere else in my code...

Orginal post follows...

Edit ends.

I have a textView which loaded in onResume() with an OnClickListener() which opens an AlertDialog. The AlertDialog has some text and three buttons, setPositivtButton, setNegativeButton and a setNeutralButton. Each time AlertDialog is opened, I want to change the text of the neutral button depending on some variable. I've tried this with no success...

```
enter code here
protected void OnResume() {
    TextView text = new TextView (this);
    text.setTextColor(res.getColor(R.color.white));
    text.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(final View v) {                 
            final String str = (String) v.getTag();
            String buttonText = "Jump";
            AlertDialog.Builder showinf = new AlertDialog.Builder(v.getContext());
            showinf.setTitle("SomeTitle");
            showinf.setMessage("someMeassage");
            showinf.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    dialog.cancel();
                }
            });
            if (variable == true) buttonText = "Sit";
                else buttonText = "Jump";
            variable = !variable; //For testing purposes...
            showinf.setNeutralButton(buttonText, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()     {                        
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    // Do something
                }
            });
            showinf.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    // Do something
                }
            });
            showinf.show();
        };
    });
}
```

Is it somehow possible with some tweeks to this code, or do I have to rewrite the whole thing? Should the AlertDialog be created each time the textView is clicked or is it possible to do this directly in the setNeutralButton code?

Edit:

Changed the code a bit (variable = !variable) and nothing changes. 
Also tried this with a Dialog without success...

I'm new to android, but does setting TextView and Dialog in onResume() make it impossible to change anything until onResume() is loaded again using onClickListener as I've done?

-- 
Tommy

Comment: Are you sure `variable` boolean is changing?

Comment: Yes. Even sets variable variable like this : variable = !variable;

Answer (score -1):

Create a singleton class to hold the values u want. Then access it using the instance of that singleton class